# Symfony form use defaults from data class after submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a problem working with Symfony forms when some fields are not submitted.

I have data class `FormData` that have some defaults in it `public $page = 1`. I use that class when creating a form. When I submit a form and that specific field is not in the request the value in data class is reset to `null`. While I want it to stay in a default state (`1`) as it was initially in data class.

I have the following data class (simplified version):

```
class FormData
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Type("int")
     * @var integer
     */
    public $page = 1;
}
```

I have the form Type:

```
class FormType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('page', IntegerType::class);
        }
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'empty_data' => new FormData()
            ));
        }
    }
```

That's how I use form:

```
    // $request->has('page') is false 
    $form = $this
        ->formFactory
        ->createNamedBuilder('', EntitiesType:class, new FormData())
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $data = $form->getData(); 
    // $data->page is null while I want it to be 1
```

Is there any solution that can keep value of `$data->page` to `1`?

PS: I know that if I do `->add('page', IntegerType::class, ['empty_data' => '1'])` for the specific field configuration then the value will be set to `1` but I want it to take the value from the data class.

Comment: I was trying this one http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/use_empty_data.html but after submit the data is reset anyway.

Comment: This code is OK, as far as I see. I've just tried it and I get `$data = FormData {#740 ▼
  +page: 1
}` So it might be some other problem, not related to this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because by default for `POST` requests `handleRequest` method submits the form with `$clearMissing` parameter set to `true` (setting not send parameters to null: https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Form.php#L562). I you want to keep your default values, please use:

```
$form->submit($data, false);
```